# sql update every third day

Tags: sql, sql-update

Hi I have a temp table of results with an arrival date and departure date that I need to make an update to every third day between the arrival and departure.
Here is my output

[image: output]

The only way I can think is to use DATEADD with multiples of 3, but the days between arrival and departure can be months or even years, so I need an UPDATE that set every third day regardless of how many days

```
UPDATE #Report SET "Service" = CASE
    WHEN Date = DATEADD(DAY,3,CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Arr AS money)) AS Datetime)) THEN 'Full Service'
    WHEN Date = DATEADD(DAY,6,CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Arr AS money)) AS Datetime)) THEN 'Full Service'
    WHEN Date = DATEADD(DAY,9,CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Arr AS money)) AS Datetime)) THEN 'Full Service'
    WHEN Date = DATEADD(DAY,12,CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Arr AS money)) AS Datetime)) THEN 'Full Service'
    WHEN Date = DATEADD(DAY,15,CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Arr AS money)) AS Datetime)) THEN 'Full Service'
    WHEN Date = DATEADD(DAY,18,CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Arr AS money)) AS Datetime)) THEN 'Full Service'
    WHEN Date = DATEADD(DAY,21,CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Arr AS money)) AS Datetime)) THEN 'Full Service'
...
etc
ELSE 'Restricted Service' END
```

Can anyone think of a solution please?

Answer (score 2):

I would expect something like this:

```
UPDATE #Report
    SET Service = (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, Arr, Date) % 3 = 0
                        THEN 'Full Service'
                        ELSE 'Restricted Service'
                   END);
```

I cannot fathom what the conversion to `money` is doing in your version of the query.

Comment: the original Arrival date included the time (ie: 09:00:00), my "Date" column was set to midnight, so converted Arr to money then back to datetime to return as 00:00:00.000 so it matched :)

Comment: @Kate . . . You can just convert to `date` to remove the time component.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution:

Added a Rank to the source table

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY RoomID ORDER BY Date) AS Ranking

Divided rank by 3

UPDATE #x SET Ranking2 = CAST(Ranking AS DECIMAL(20,2))/3 

Update only where this is a whole number

UPDATE #Report SET "Service" = 
    CASE WHEN FS.Ranking2 = ROUND(FS.Ranking2, 0) THEN 'Full Service'
    ELSE 'Restricted Service' END
```

Please let me know if there is a better way though thankyou